# SQL query to select an email address within a string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm looking for help to create a SQL query to extract the email address from a text field which holds a json object like this:

```
{"objectType":"Agent","mbox":"mailto:testuser@test.com","name":"Test User"}
```

For the sake of the example I'll call the table `tblUsers` and the field `UserObject`.

I can get everything after the string `"mailto:"`, but need to strip the rest of the string after the address. Obviously the address might not always end with ".com".

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: sorry, SQL Server 2019

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, in the end I ended up going with JSON_VALUE(UserObject, '$.mbox') as I can manipulate the resulting string later

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach is to parse the JSON data using `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(UserObject, '$.mbox'), 'mailto:', '') AS Email
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"objectType":"Agent","mbox":"mailto:testuser@test.com","name":"Test User"}')
) tblUsers (UserObject)
```

Result:

```
Email
-----------------
testuser@test.com
```

If you need to extract all data, stored as JSON, and if the JSON has a fixed structure, you may try to use `OPENJSON()` with an explicit schema:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"objectType":"Agent","mbox":"mailto:testuser@test.com","name":"Test User"}')
) tblUsers (UserObject)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tblUsers.UserObject) WITH (
   objectType varchar(100) '$.objectType',
   mbox varchar(100) '$.mbox',
   name varchar(100) '$.name'
) cteApply
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OPENJSON` to get the value, and then `STUFF` to remove the prefix. I use `CHARINDEX` here just incase the prefix can vary:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"objectType":"Agent","mbox":"mailto:testuser@test.com","name":"Test User"}'

SELECT STUFF(mbox,1,CHARINDEX(':',mbox),'') AS EmailAddress
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (mbox nvarchar(255));
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using the base string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(email,
                 CHARINDEX('"mailto:', email) + 8,
                 LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('",', email,
                              CHARINDEX('"mailto:', email) + 8) - 3) AS email
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '{"objectType":"Agent","mbox":"mailto:testuser@test.com","name":"Test User"}' AS email
)
```

Honestly a JSON based approach is the best option here, but if you might have your JSON as a fragment in some other text, then it would not be parsable as JSON, and this approach might have some merit.